# Add a maximum of 200 elements on en empty 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am having a Python program that creates lists of 3 elements.

```
['a', 'was', 'mother']
```

and adds them on an empty list,

```
output_text=[]
while True:
    candidates = [t for t in lines if t[0:2] == last_two]
    if not candidates:
        break
    
    triplet = random.choice(candidates)
    last_two = triplet[1:3]
    output_text.append(triplet)
    print('\n Επιλογή Matching Τριάδας: \n',triplet)
    print('\n Δύο Τελευταίες Λέξεις Matching Τριάδας: \n',last_two)
    print(output_text)
```

I want to create an if statement that keeps adding the 3-element lists to output_text until 200 words (total elements) are being stored.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have code which _"adds them on an empty list"_. Please show the code you have.

Comment: Not sure why is that necessary since that I may have to represent my whole project. Anyway, I will try to show the code for the empty list I mention.

Comment: Thanks. The code you have shown help understand your problem. I see two things you should do for a start:  change `output_text.append` to `output_text.extend` and add an `if len(output_text) >= 200: break`

Comment: Can't seem to be able to solve this. I don't know where to put if len(output_text) >= 200: break and my program doesn't keep adding any additional triplets to my output list automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could e.g. combine `itertools.cycle` and `.islice`, or just use modulo `%`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, cycle                                     
>>> lst = ['a', 'was', 'mother']                                            
>>> list(islice(cycle(lst), 10))                                            
['a', 'was', 'mother', 'a', 'was', 'mother', 'a', 'was', 'mother', 'a']
>>> [lst[i % len(lst)] for i in range(10)]                                 
['a', 'was', 'mother', 'a', 'was', 'mother', 'a', 'was', 'mother', 'a']
```

(Technically, this does not append to an empty list but creates the list in one go, but I assume that's okay.)

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic solution would involve `itertools.cycle`, which is an iterator that yields items from a given iterable indefinitely, and `itertools.islice` to grab the first 200 items from the cycle-iterator:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

words = list(islice(cycle(("a", "was", "mother")), 200))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier done with a while loop, like this:

```
lst = ['a', 'was', 'mother']                                                                                    
output_text = []

while len(output_text) < 200:
    if len(output_text) - 200 > 3:
        output_text += lst
    else:
        output_text += lst[:(200-len(output_text))%3]

print(output_text)
```